# What is the intended use of SUS and sub-examples in Specs for Scala?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs

Specs provides two different means of hierarchically structuring your specifications. One is by defining a "system under specification" and the other is by making sub-examples (one example is one specification/test statement).

Can someone please answer or point to a website what the intended usage of those different mechanisms is in general? I'm also curious about the reusing of specifications/examples.

### My Use-Case

In particular I have a project that contains different algorithms A to compute some output X given a specific input examples Y. Should I choose the algorithms A to be the *SUS*, so that I can reuse a setup like "must compute the correct result for example Y_1; must compute the correct result for example Y_2; ..."? Or should I specify the different examples to be the *SUS*, so that I get "must be solvable by algorithm A_1; must be solvable by algorithm A_2; ..."?

What shall I turn into *SUS* and what into sub-examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the system under specification (SUS) is the code that you're specifying, not the data.

Then the main differences between the SUS and normal examples/sub-examples in ***specs*** is the fact that a SUS has several additional methods to set the context such as the [->- method](http://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/DeclareSpecifications#Shared_contexts).

What I would actually suggest in your case, if the data is effectively the same for each algorithm is simply to define a method to create your examples:

```
def examplesMustPassFor(algo: Algorithm) = {
  "The algo "+algo.name should {
    "pass the data set 1" in { ... }
    "pass the data set 2" in { ... }
    "pass the data set 3" in { ... }
  }
}

examplesMustPassFor(algo1)
examplesMustPassFor(algo2)
examplesMustPassFor(algo3)
```

Another important point that I want to mention is that the [***specs***](http://code.google.com/p/specs) project has now been superseded by [***specs2***](http://specs2.org) so you might want to check this one out if you're just starting writing your specifications.

Of course don't hesitate to ask more specific questions with code samples on the [mailing-list](http://groups.google.com/group/specs2-users) if you want.

Eric.

Comment: Specifying a method as you suggest is what I did after asking the question. One problem that I am facing is that the objects for my algorithm receive the problem instance on creation. So I have to pass a function that maps Problem to AlgorithmForProblem into the function that specifies the examples. Well, it's not that much of a problem in Scala...